# Hair Particles Disappearing when Model Turns His Head

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

Minor problem here. I have a character I've made and he has some stubble on his face that I've used the particle system for. It all looks good through the viewport, HOWEVER, when I render the sucker some of his stubble disappears when he turns his head to the left. Once he turns his head back it reappears.
I've tried remedying this by converting the particles to a mesh but it doesn't look as good. I do have the subsurface modifier below the particles though. If I put it above the particles it doesn't render at all so maybe I've done something wrong there.
There must be an easy fix to this somewhere in the settings but I can't find it so far.
Can anyone set me straight?
Many thanks!
Mark